# Velocidad de Carga MariaDB en tablas vista

Tags: mysql

tengo un problema con una base de datos en MariaDB con una vista. Antiguamente la base de datos estaba alojada en otra subscripcion de PLESK y tenía una tabla vista que tardaba en cargar 0.08 segundos. Esto estaba hecho por el informático antiguo.

Vista:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`testuser`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `monederotemp`  
AS SELECT 
`a`.`imagen` AS `imagen`, 
concat(`a`.`nombre`,' ',`a`.`apellidos`) AS `nombre`, 
`a`.`edad` AS `edad`, 
concat(`a`.`sexo`,' (',`b`.`nombre`,')') AS `sexo`, 
ifnull(
  if(
      (
        (select count(0) from `tpv` where (`tpv`.`iduser` = `a`.`iduser`)) > 0
      ), 
    (
        select 
        ifnull(
            (
            ifnull((select sum(`monedero`.`dinero`) from `monedero` where (`monedero`.`iduser` = `tpv`.`iduser`)), 0) - ifnull(sum(((select `productos`.`precio` from `productos` where (`productos`.`id` = `tpv`.`idproducto`)) * `tpv`.`cantidad`)),0)
            ),
            0
        ) AS `saldo` 
        from `tpv` 
        where (`tpv`.`iduser` = `a`.`iduser`)
    ), 
    (select sum(`monedero`.`dinero`) from `monedero` where (`monedero`.`iduser` = `a`.`iduser`))
  ),
  0
) AS `saldo`,
ifnull((select sum(`monedero`.`dinero`) from `monedero` where (`monedero`.`iduser` = `a`.`iduser`)),0) AS `dinero`, 
`a`.`campamento` AS `campamento`, `a`.`iduser` AS `iduser` 
FROM (`inscritos` `a` join `campamentos` `b`) 
WHERE (`a`.`campamento` = `b`.`id`) ;
```

El problema reside que se ha migrado la base de datos a otra subscripción en el mismo plesk debido a que ahora llevo yo la informatica y al migrar la vista ahora me tarda en cargar la tabla 19.8 segundos de media, lo cual hace que la aplicacion funcione muy lenta (Las vistas en la app estan monstadas en server-side datatables)

La verdad que estoy un poco perdido, he probado en plesk ver si hay alguna diferencia en las subscripciones pero no encuentro el problema con la diferencia en tiempos de carga.

Alguien sabria cual podría ser el problema o que debería de mirar en PLESK?

Perdonad la poca información, pero estoy muy perdido en esto. La BD sería MariaDB version 5.5.68

Comment: El primer paso es usar [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-explain-analyze/) sobre la consulta para entender dónde se demora. Siempre. En tu caso, es sobre la consulta que crea la vista (el SELECT). Los motivos pueden ser desde un OPTIMIZE TABLE que falta hacer, hasta índices perdidos o cambios en el volumen de datos...

Comment: Esa versión de MariaDB es [muy antigua (del 2012)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/changes-improvements-in-mariadb-55/). Actualmente la estable es la 10.3 creo. A ver si va a ser eso.